# How to get multiple image from folder in laravel 4

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I'm trying to get multiple image from public/img folder. The images that I'm trying to get is a result of multiple join table

```
$tayang=DB::table('detiltayang')
    ->join('tayang','detiltayang.idTayang','=','tayang.idTayang')
    ->join('bioskop','tayang.idBioskop','=','bioskop.idBioskop')
    ->join('film','tayang.idFilm','=','film.idFilm')
    ->where('detiltayang.flag','=','1')
    ->where('detiltayang.active','=','1')
    ->get();

    return Response::json($tayang);
```

How can I get all the image that match the condition from public/img folder? thanks in advance

Comment: More information needed in order to understand your structure. With looking at this fluent query, all I can see is you are polling some movies. Do you have a image table, what is the relation type one-to-one, many-to-many, one-to-many.  or do you store images in public/img by movie folder name or id?